# Javascript closure & "that" instead of "this" in a specific example

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, closures, this

I know this subject had been dealt a lot here, but I saw this specific example on the Pluralsight JS design pattern course, and I'll be glad for your help understanding the closure there.

This is the example:

```
var Calc = function(start) {
    var that = this;

    this.add = function(x) {
        start = start + x;
        return that;
    };

    this.multiply = function(x) {
        start = start * x;
        return that;
    };

    this.equals = function(callback) {
        callback(start);
        return that;
    };
}

new Calc(0)
    .add(1)
    .add(2)
    .multiply(3)
    .equals(function(result){
        console.log(result); // returns 9
    });
```

Here's the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/3yJ8Y/5/

I'll be VERY glad for:

1. Understanding the "that" use. Why do we need it in this specific
   example? it does the same with "this". Can you pls give examples and explain when do we need to do "var that = this"?
2. Understanding this way of creating functions from an object. why do we have to use "this" and then .functionName? like this.add = ...
3. A detailed and extensive explanation for this very specific closure example.

Thank you so much!

Comment: `that` is actually wrong here (since it's not a local variable). `this` would've been better.

Comment: You don't need `that` in this case, `this` will work just fine, see http://jsfiddle.net/3yJ8Y/2/

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about the closure? Was there no explanation at the course, at what point did you get lost? `start` is a local variable to every `Calc` invocation.

Comment: I added the "var" before "that", sorry for the typo.
I do understand the use of the "start" var in the closure. I'll be glad for explanations for what I wrote there. Thanks!

Comment: This is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword. `new` does some magic but the important thing to understand is how `this` works. Bottomline, `this` depends on how you call a function, it can be implicit or explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @elclanrs for reminding me of things I had internalized and forgotten...

## That

The important thing here is that `that`... is unnecessary.

I'll quote an article that @elclanrs linked in his comment on the above post:

[Scope In Javascript](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/)

> JavaScript establishes an execution context for the function call, setting this to the object referenced by whatever came before the last ”.”

Because each method is called with the outer `Calc` before it's dot, the `this` value inside that method is assigned as the outer object.

The outer object, in turn, is its own brand new, self-contained scope because it was created with the `new` keyword:

> When `new`[`Calc`]`()` is executed, a completely new object is created transparently in the background. [`Calc`] is called, and its this keyword is set to reference that new object.

([Scope in Javascript, again, with my edits in brackets](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/)).

Now you might be wondering, "How is this:

```
.add(1)
.add(2)
.multiply(3)
```

... keeping the right scope? You said that whatever is before the `.` is passed in as the `this` variable in this situation!?"

Absolutely true, and in this situation, each method is returning `this`, which allows method chaining. (They're actually returning `that`, but we already determined that was an unnecessary variable in this context).

## Why use `that`

First of all, let me say I prefer `var self = this` over `var that = this` but there are arguments either way.

Let's arbitrarily modify the object to have a method that looks like this:

```
this.getInternalThis = function(){
    var internalThis = function(){
        console.log( this );
    }
}
```

First of all, let's get this out of the way: this example is stupid, but you'll see things **like** this - a function defined in other scopes - all the time.

Here are the important things to notice:

1. It's called by name, and nothing more (no prefixed `.` notation, for example)
2. ... that's it!

When a function is called this way, the engine has to figure out something to assign `this` as in the scope of the function. It defaults to `window`.
If you were to run this code, you would get `Window` in the console.

Now, what if we wanted `this` inside that internal function call to be the calling value of `this`?
**This** situation is where you need a `that` variable.  We can modify the function to look like:

```
this.getInternalThis = function(){
    var that = this,
        internalThis = function(){
            console.log( that );
        };
}
```

Now when you run this method, you get the value of the calling object in the console.
In my case it was `Object { add=function(), multiply=function(), equals=function(), getInternalThis=function()}`.

Sometimes, that's what you need or expect, so that's why you would use a `var that = this` declaration.

## Using `this.` to define a method

As I mentioned earlier:

> Because each method is called with the outer `Calc` before it's dot, the `this` value inside that method is assigned as the outer object.

Remember that `this` in the scope of `Calc()` is a reference to the *new* Calc object, so each method is being given the Calc object as the value of `this` (remember, it's before the `.`!) when they enter their new scope from that context.

Hopefully this gives you a little info on how JavaScript scopes and the assignment of `this` works.

Comment: I think this explanation is misleading, `this` isn't assigned to anything until the function is called. It is the `new` keyword which creates a new object for `this`, otherwise it will default to `window`. The reference to `that` is unnecessary in this case because using dot notation on the instance implicitly sets `this` to be the receiver. Using prototypes doesn't make `this` magically refer to the instance, it is the way you call the function that matters.

Comment: @elclanrs You're very right. Could you edit my answer or post another to make that clear?

Answer (score 0):

`start` becomes a global variable of the `Calc` object

Each method of the `Calc` object (`add`, `multiple`, `equals`) references that same global variable

```
new Calc(0)            // <- sets start to 0
    .add(1)            // calls add() <- sets start to 1
    .add(2)            // calls add() <- sets start to 3
    .multiply(3)       // calls multiple() <- sets start to 9
    .equals(function(result){
        console.log(result); // returns 9
    });
```